# Function to return an array of extended in VCL Form Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Returning array using a function in Console type can be done but I am trying to make a function which takes an integer n as input and returns an array of extended in VCL form of Delphi. How can we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern versions of Delphi you should use the generic array, [`TArray<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TArray). Like this:

```
function Foo(N: Integer): TArray<Extended>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, N);
  for i := 0 to N-1 do begin
    Result[i] := i;
  end;
end;
```

I would stress that it is likely a mistake to be using `Extended`. This is a rather unusual and badly performing 10 byte floating point type. The type is only available on a limited number of processors. Almost all real world floating point calculations are performed using `Single` or `Double`, the 4 byte and 8 byte IEEE-754 floating point data types.

Answer (score 2):

If my memory serves me correct, this has to be done by re-typing it ie:

```
type
  TResultType: array of extended;

function DoSomthing(): TResultType
begin
  SetLength(Result, 2);
  Result[0] := 1.2;
  Result[1] := 3.4;
end;
```

Comment: it throws an error 'TResultType doesn't have a corresponding component'. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The function is used to generate an array(X[n]) which can be called during a procedure to return a particular value at the current value of n.

Comment: @Jack The code in the question does not lead to an error. Please don't expect us to comment on your code that we cannot see that you won't show us. I urge you to slow down and learn the basics before coding.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a VCL/Console issue as function declarations are not dependent on the type of application you are writing.

Delphi (or any Pascal) functions can return any named data type. As long as the array type is declared in the type section, a function can handle it.

eg.

```
type
  ExtArray : array of extended;

function IntToArray(i:integer):ExtArray;
begin
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Looks like Slade just beat me to it!